# Attribute set in onCreate, causes NullPointer in onResume

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, parse-platform

So, in my onCreate() method, I'm calling a Parse query and returning a single ParseObject that is tied to a global variable, like so...

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            String quizId = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("quizId");
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> getQuiz = ParseQuery.getQuery("Quiz");
            getQuiz.getInBackground(quizId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseObject result, ParseException e) {
                    mQuiz = result;
                    mQuestionRelation = mQuiz.getRelation("questions");
                    Log.d("KMH", "mQuiz: " + mQuiz.getObjectId());
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The console returns this as proof it's getting the object:

```
11-19 03:12:40.104  14876-14876/com.codejunkie.games.quizie D/KMH﹕ Parse returned quiz: HTgGeY3NJL
```

Then, I set my global ParseRelation variable to a relation of the returned ParseObject. Now, inside of my onResume() method, I'm using that Relation global variable and it's getting a `NullPointerException`.

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> getAnswers = mQuestionRelation.getQuery();
        getAnswers.addDescendingOrder("createdAt");
        getAnswers.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> answers, ParseException e) {
                mAnswers = answers;

                String[] answerText = new String[mAnswers.size()];
                int i = 0;
                for(ParseObject answer : mAnswers) {
                    answerText[i] = answer.getString("answer");
                    i++;
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout._item_question, R.id.questionText, answerText);

                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the line with the `NullPointer`:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> getAnswers = mQuestionRelation.getQuery();
```

**ANSWER:**

I wasn't setting my globals in the main thread due to the .getInBackground call to Parse. Here's how I fixed it:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            String quizId = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("quizId");
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> getQuiz = ParseQuery.getQuery("Quiz");
            try {
                mQuiz = getQuiz.get(quizId);
                mQuestionRelation = mQuiz.getRelation("questions");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

And to handle the case of mQuestionRelation being `null`:

```
if (mQuestionRelation != null) {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> getQuestions = mQuestionRelation.getQuery();
            getQuestions.addAscendingOrder("createdAt");
            getQuestions.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> questions, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        mQuestions = questions;

                        String[] answerText = new String[mQuestions.size()];
                        int i = 0;
                        for (ParseObject question : mQuestions) {
                            answerText[i] = question.getString("question");
                            i++;
                        }

                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout._item_question, R.id.questionText, answerText);

                        mQuestionsList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Rather than adding your solution to the question, you can create an answer and accept that, if you think your answer is of use to other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get your Relation in a different thread (since it is executed in background). This means that the set is not actually done in onCreate() but sometimes later, so the 'done' method might be called after onResume() depending on how slow the querying is. If that happens, then you'll get a null pointer exception indeed.

Comment: How can I work around this? I need to set mQuiz to the returned result, but I need to do it in the main thread.

Comment: Figured it out! Updating w/ solution now!

Comment: call mQuestionRelation.getQuery() in first query's result